# `acpi=off` results in `BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference`

Tags: boot, kernel-modules, acpi, nixos

## Background

I have been getting spontaneous crashes on my newly built NixOS machine. I am trying out different configuration options to see if I can avoid them.

Here is my `journalctl -b -1 -p 3`:

```
Jun 24 15:55:27 mus kernel: ACPI Error: Needed [Integer/String/Buffer], found [Region]         (ptrval) (20180105/exresop-424)
Jun 24 15:55:27 mus kernel: ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, Could not execute arguments for [IOB2] (Region) (20180105/nsinit-426)
Jun 24 15:55:27 mus systemd-udevd[761]: Specified group 'render' unknown
Jun 24 15:55:27 mus systemd-udevd[761]: Specified group 'kvm' unknown
Jun 24 15:55:27 mus systemd-modules-load[755]: Failed to find module 'snd_pcm_oss'
Jun 24 16:08:12 mus pulseaudio[6069]: bind(): Address already in use
Jun 24 16:08:12 mus pulseaudio[6069]: Failed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
Jun 24 16:08:12 mus pulseaudio[6069]: Module load failed.
Jun 24 16:08:12 mus pulseaudio[6069]: Failed to initialize daemon.
Jun 24 16:12:22 mus systemd-udevd[761]: Specified group 'render' unknown
Jun 24 16:12:22 mus systemd-udevd[761]: Specified group 'kvm' unknown
```

The first ACPI errors are suspicious, so I tried rebooting with `acpi=off` in my `boot.kernelParams`.

## The Error

Unfortunately, this configuration results in a kernel null-deref error on bootup.

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008
```

**Full screenshot**

[image: full screenshot]

I found no ACPI options in my BIOS (mobo is ASUS Prime X470-Pro AMD Ryzen 2 AM4 DDR4 DP HDMI M.2 USB 3.1 ATX). So perhaps there are some compatibility issues that I am missing.

What is the reason that I am unable to activate `acpi=off`?

## Versions

I am on Linux kernel 4.16.17, and NixOS 18.03.

Comment: For questions like this which require troubleshooting, you're much better off asking on the NixOS mailing list or the #nixos channel on freenode.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with kernel `4.18.12`. B450 chipset with Ryzen 2, so a similar setup to yours. Different call trace but the exact same `BUG` line. Arch Linux, so I guess this is an upstream issue...

Comment: After a few months, my spontaneous crashes have ceased to occur. Unfortunately I am not able to credit any particular change.